# C++ measuring memory usage during MergeSort

Tags: c++, windows

I want to measure RAM memory usage after MergeSort in C++ on 10 000 000 random elements (self-written MergeSor). I use *MEMORYSTATUSEX* function to count it like this

```
#define DIV 1048576 //conversion to MB
[...]
MEMORYSTATUSEX memInfo;
memInfo.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);
GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memInfo);
DWORDLONG totalVirtualMem = memInfo.ullTotalPageFile;
DWORDLONG totalPhysMem = memInfo.ullTotalPhys; //RAM
DWORDLONG availmemory = memInfo.ullAvailVirtual;
DWORDLONG allmemory = memInfo.ullTotalVirtual;
mergeSort(arr, 0, size - 1); 
std::cout << "total Phys memory " <<  (allmemory- availmemory)/DIV << std::endl;
```

This returns me value of around 54 MB, which i found unbelievable, because same algorithm in Python takes around 520 MB (measured using *tracemalloc* ) which is why i think that value measured in C++ is wrong. I tried to google another answers for this and all i got is using third-part software or unix solutions. Is there any C++ equivalent of python's tracemalloc?

Comment: You only get memory status *once*, before calling the function (i'ts a one-time snapshot at the time of the `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` call). You don't actually measure the amount of memory the function (and its algorithm) itself uses. I'm sure there are tools that can help you, but they might not be free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found solution, a little overkill but it works. You have to do a little workaround, which is measuring memory every time function mergeSort is called and then check if the current value of memory is greater than previous

```
int memoryTaken = 0; //global variable, not very elegant but works
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) {
if (l >= r) {
    return;//returns recursively
}
int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
mergeSort(arr, l, m);
mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);
merge(arr, l, m, r);

MEMORYSTATUSEX memInfo;
memInfo.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);
GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memInfo);
DWORDLONG totalVirtualMem = memInfo.ullTotalPageFile;
DWORDLONG totalPhysMem = memInfo.ullTotalPhys; //RAM
DWORDLONG availmemory = memInfo.ullAvailVirtual;
DWORDLONG allmemory = memInfo.ullTotalVirtual;
int tmp = (allmemory - availmemory) / DIV;
if (tmp > memoryTaken) {
    memoryTaken =(allmemory - availmemory) / DIV;
}

}
```

Disadvantag is that program will be much slower than without it, but value of memory is precise. I chcecked it with Visual Studio memory profiler and i read same value.